# Print line of pattern match in Perl regex

Tags: regex, perl

I am looking for a keyword in a multiline input using a regex like this,

```
if($input =~ /line/mi)
{
    # further processing
}
```

The data in the input variable could be like this,

```
this is
multi line text
to be matched
using perl
```

The code works and matches the keyword **line** correctly. However, I would also like to obtain the line where the pattern was matched - "multi line text" - and store it into a variable for further processing. How do I go about this?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: `my @match = grep /line/mi, split /\n/, $input` perhaps? Although the `/m` modifier is completely useless in that regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can grep out the lines into an array, which will then also serve as your conditional:

```
my @match = grep /line/mi, split /\n/, $input;
if (@match) {
    # ... processing
}
```

Comment: You should remove the `/m` that has no effect here, since there are no instances of `^` or `$`.

Answer (score 0):

TLP's answer is better but you can do:

```
if ($input =~ /([^\n]+line[^\n]+)/i) {
    $line = $1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd look if the match is in the multiline-String and in case it is, split it into lines and then look for the correct index number (starting with 0!):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $data=<<END;
this is line
multi line text
to be matched
using perl
END

if ($data =~ /line/mi){
    my @lines = split(/\r?\n/,$data);
    for (0..$#lines){
        if ($lines[$_] =~ /line/){
            print "LineNr of Match: " . $_ . "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try his?
This works for me. $1 represents the capture of regex inside `(` and  `)`
Provided there is only one match in one of the lines.If there are matches in multiple lines, then only the first one will be captured.

```
if($var=~/(.*line.*)/)
{
print $1
}
```

If you want to capture all the lines which has the string line then use below:

```
my @a;
push @a,$var=~m/(.*line.*)/g;
print "@a";
```

Comment: What if I'm passing arguments to my perl script - will this work correctly in that case?

Comment: and what is the argument that you are passing?

Comment: Never mind that, I was confused between argument syntax for shell script and perl. Since $1 denotes the first argument to a shell script, I mixed it up with the perl for the same, and thought it would lead to printing of the argument value instead of the regex output :-)